# From the general decomposition of electric field to one polarized along $\hat{\textbf{x}}$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, polarization, classical-field-theory

In the gauge $A^0=\nabla\cdot\textbf{A}=0$, starting from the Fourier decomposition of $\textbf{A}(\textbf{x},t)$, the electric field $\textbf{E}(\textbf{x},t)$ is obtained as $$\textbf{E}(\textbf{x},t)=-\frac{\partial\textbf{A}}{\partial t}=(-i)\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{\frac{E_\textbf{p}}{2}}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2}[\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}_r(\textbf{p})a_{\textbf{p},r}e^{-ip\cdot x}-\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^*_r(\textbf{p})a^\dagger_{\textbf{p},r}e^{+ip\cdot x}].\tag{1}$$ where $\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}_{1,2}$ are two independent states of polarization.

Let $\hat{\textbf{p}}=(0,0,1)$. Suppose we want an electric field $\textbf{E}(\textbf{x},t)$ polarized along $\hat{\textbf{x}}$. How does one choose $\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}_{1,2}(\textbf{p})$, such that the $\textbf{E}(\textbf{x},t)$ is along $\hat{\textbf{x}}$? Neither linear nor circular polarizations seem to work! If we choose $\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}_{1}=\hat{\textbf{x}}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}_{2}=\hat{\textbf{y}}$, $\textbf{E}$ is not completely along $\hat{\textbf{x}}$. Same for $\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}_{1,2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{\textbf{x}}+i\hat{\textbf{y}})$.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Neither linear nor circular polarizations seem to work"*? What did you try that *failed* to work? Depending on what $\epsilon$ you choose, the values of $a_{p,r}$ you have to choose for a field with a particular polarization will be different, but I don't see how that can "fail" unless you choose $\epsilon$ that are not a basis for the space of polarizations.

Comment: I am trying to find a suitable $\epsilon_{1,2}$ such that the electric field is completely along $\hat{\textbf{x}}$. Does that make sense? For example, I chose $\epsilon_{1,2}$ as $\hat{x},\hat{y}$. What about the last sentence of the question? Does that make sense? @ACuriousMind

Comment: No, what you're saying does not make sense to me. You seem to be misunderstanding how this decomposition works at all: The $\epsilon$ are a *fixed* conventional choice made once for all fields, "finding $\epsilon$ such that the electric field is completely along the x-axis" is a non-sensical thing to want to do. The components that vary with the specific field $E$ being decomposed are the $a_{\vec p,r}$, since they are the Fourier coefficients - i.e. you should be trying to find $a_{\vec p,r}$ such that the field is along the x-axis, given a certain fixed choice of the $\epsilon$.

Comment: So if $\epsilon_{1,2}$ are respectively $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$, the total E-field will be along x-axis if we choose, the coefficients of $\hat{y}$ (say, denoted by $a_{p,2}$ and $a^\dagger_{p,2}$) to be zero. Is this fine? @ACuriousMind